# C++11 type deduction vs const char *

Tags: c++, c++11, char, auto, gotw

In [GotW 94](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/), Herb Sutter draws a distinction between the "classic C++" declaration

```
const char* s = "Hello";
```

and the "modern" style

```
auto s = "Hello";
```

He tells us that there's a "subtle difference in the type of `s`, where the `auto` style is more correct". [Edited to add: comments suggest that this might not be a fair representation of what Sutter actually meant; see discussion below.]

But... what's the difference? I was under the impression that a `const char *` is the correct way to refer to a string literal. Further, when I asked my debugger (lldb), it seems to think the types are actually the same:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1756c2, 0x0000000100000f8f test`main + 31 at test.cc:4, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000f8f test`main + 31 at test.cc:4
   1    int main(void) {
   2        const char* s = "Hello";
   3        auto t = "Hello";
-> 4        return 0;
   5    }
(lldb) fr v
(const char *) s = 0x0000000100000f91 "Hello"
(const char *) t = 0x0000000100000f91 "Hello"
```

Where's the subtle difference Sutter refers to?

Comment: That is an extremely subtle difference I'd say.

Comment: There's no difference. He might be thinking that `auto` would deduce an array instead, but it won't.

Comment: Sutter actually states "for example, can you spot a subtle difference in the type of s, where the auto style is more correct?" Your paraphrase gives a completely different meaning to the statement.

Comment: Doesn't the auto version deduce type of const char[5]?

Comment: @kiss-o-matic: No, array-to-pointer conversion is applied during type deduction.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic No. There's no difference.

Comment: Note also that `s` and `t` have been coalesced (they have the same address).

Comment: On nth reading, @remyabel may be correct, but I'm struggling to grasp exactly what Sutter's point is, if it's not what I interpreted it as!

Comment: Could it be a charset issue?

Comment: @PaulRubel: No, the type of an ordinary string literal is always "array of `const char`", from which `const char*` will be deduced by `auto`.

Comment: @remyabel he heavily implied that there's a difference with that statement. And if there really isn't a difference, I'm not sure what point he was trying to make.

Comment: I checked if Herb's statement could be a simple typo, but it looks like it was just a misunderstanding of his about the effect of `auto`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not entirely clear on what Herb stated (context is important), but anyway the types are the same.

Comment: He didn't say any more (in that article) than the quote given in the question. I'm pretty sure you're right, and there's no difference, subtle or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks to this, and to the comment by @remyabel above. I'm sure you're correct that I didn't grasp exactly what his point was, but even after a several re-readings I'm not sure what he actually _is_ saying. That the auto version is more maintainable if there is a subtle change to the types, perhaps.

Answer (score 10):

I posted this to [Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/):

> What do you think is the “subtle difference in the type of s, where
>   the auto style is more correct”? See
>   [C++11 type deduction vs const char *](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27550539)

And here's his reply:

> I think I had in mind that the auto version deduced an array, which it
>   doesn’t. If I had something else in mind, I’ve forgotten it now, so
>   I’ve removed that phrase and added your moniker to the
>   Acknowledgments. Thanks for the feedback!