# Using auto foo = "bar" vs std::string in C++11

Tags: c++, string, performance, c++11, auto

I'm searching for a substring using `string::find` in C++. When I defined a string using `const auto` and used the variable later down, **eclipse** replaced `.` with `->`.

I found this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550539/c11-type-deduction-vs-const-char) which concludes that `auto foo = "bar"` is deduced to a `(const char *) foo = "bar"`. So eclipse is correct converting `.` to `->` even though I was a bit baffled to begin with. I assumed incorrectly `auto` would become `std::string`.

Would there be a **downside** deducing `auto foo = "bar"` to `std::string` instead of `const char *` ? Increased code size, slower performance?

Comment: The type of `"bar"` is `const char[4]`. I don't know why you think this should be automatically converted to a `std::string`.

Comment: I think you are confusing that fact that you can assign a `const char *` or `const char [4]` to a string: `std::string str = "bar";` with the fact that anything between quotes is just a normal const char array.

Comment: If you want the type to be `std::string` say so. Don't use `auto` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code could have a million classes that can be constructed implicitly from a `const char *`. Why should `std::string` be chosen?

`auto` simply saves some keyboard typing you if you want a variable with **the same type of the expression¹**, not if you want to create a different object.

(1) more or less; things as always get somewhat hairy with C++...

Answer (score 3):

Well, likely, you have just answered your own question. std::string takes slightly more space (it has size counter), its creation involves dynamic allocation etc.

The lack of a complex string type may seem an anachronism nowadays, but since C++ is oriented toward a complete replacement of C with its low-level efficiency, it's pretty explainable.

Moreover, `std::string` is just a library class.  you can choose a different string type, e.g. [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) or [std::experimental::string_view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view), if your task requires it. BTW, `string_view` is much more similar to `const char[]` since it doesn't provide dynamic manipulations at all and can be used in [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed like talking to someone and the next day this sudden realization came to me why auto defaults to char*. I appreciate it a lot you all three took the time answering.

Answer (score 2):

"Foobar" is a string literal and not a `std::string`. This is stored as `const char[7]` in a read only section of your binary.

`std::string` te type has an implicit conversion from `const char *` because it has a single argument constructor without it being explicit which is invoked if you write: `std::string s = "foobar";`. Note that the default argument of allocator is assigned on the constructor.

Using `const auto` gives you the actual type instead of a converted type. So converting a string literal to `std::string` actually creates another object that references the literal.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: `"foobar"`'s type is not `char const *`, it's `char const[7]` (6 `char`s + terminating null character)

Comment: Yeah you're right. But there is little practical difference in this case.